# Listener for JWT token expiration event

Tags: angularjs, jwt, token

I have an AngularJS app that uses JWT Tokens for authentication.

My app is a Single Page Application that never reloads; i would like to 
have a sort of listener that advices me when the token expires.

I would like to avoid a setTimeout to verify the token expiration,
is there a better way to know that the JWT token is not valid anymore?

Comment: You could check the token expiry before each request, and if it has expired, get a new one at that point

Comment: You use the JWT to call webservices, right? and when the token is expired or not valid then the webservice returns a 401, right? 
So you could just handle the 401 and get a new token when the server says it is expired. 
but better would be to have a central place to call the webservices and check if the token is expired before you do the call to the server, get a new token and then call the webservice with the new token.